# How to fix this app.post() and app.get() error in nodejs and MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been trying to post data in mongo sb using nodejs and mongodb but it's only getting posted when I use app.get instead of app.post but in reality it should work otherwise right?

Whenever I replace app.post with app.get it starts posting data. I am confused.

```js
var schema = mongo.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number
});

var Model = mongo.model("model", schema, "myCollection");

var doc1 = new Model({
    name: "John",
    age: 21
});

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
const getres = 'you got the request';

app.get('/get', async (req, res, next) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    console.log(name);
    club.collection.save(data);
    next();
});

app.post('/post', async (req, res, next) => {
    doc1.save(function (err, doc) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log("Document inserted succussfully!");
    });
    next();
});

app.listen(7000);

mongo.connect('mongodb+srv://himu:pass@cluster0.szkh7.mongodb.net/test', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
```

Comment: I'd guess the post isn't working because you have no CORS configuration, only a simple request can work, but give a [mre] - how are you making requests to that endpoint, and what do you see when you do?

Comment: No errors in console at all?

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be fine, if you can save data using the route.

Did you hit the url in the browser to save the data ?

Going to a route in the browser will only make a GET request.

Use any tool to make POST request to the url ('/post') such as POSTMAN